# How can I the sort this hash based on the c value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

```
h = {"Collectible\\nGames"     =>{"c"=>19},
     "Family & Friends\\nGames"=>{"c"=>71},
     "Logic Games\\n"          =>{"c"=>32},
     "Kids Games\\n"           =>{"c"=>92},
     "Classic Games\\n"        =>{"c"=>22},
     "Card Games\\n"           =>{"c"=>40},
     "Preschool\\nGames"       =>{"c"=>48}}
```

Comment: sort_by { |k,v| v[:c] }  but it passes from a hash to some type of array, sorry but im still new to ruby

Comment: Andy, I hope you don't mind how I reformatted your hash. For it to be shown as code, lines must be indented at least four spaces (or select the code and click on `{}` above). I also assigned the hash to a variable, `h`. That way readers can simply refer to `h` in answers and comments without having to define it. Ha! As I am writing this I see @John removed the definition of `h` in his code, presumably because I just stuck it into your code.

Comment: One more thing, when you give an example it's helpful for you to also show the expected or desired output. You might consider editing the question to do that. btw, one does not normally sort a hash, but you certainly can. I normally don't edit questions, but in this case it was easier to do it than for me to explain how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice ! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Your keys are the string (`"c"`), not a symbol (`:c`). You can call `to_h` on the array to get back to a hash.

```
h.sort_by{|k, v| v["c"]}.to_h 
# => {"Collectible\nGames"=>{"c"=>19}, 
     "Classic Games\n"=>{"c"=>22}, 
     "Logic Games\n"=>{"c"=>32}, 
     "Card Games\n"=>{"c"=>40}, 
     "Preschool\nGames"=>{"c"=>48}, 
     "Family & Friends\nGames"=>{"c"=>71}, 
     "Kids Games\n"=>{"c"=>92}}
```